# need a little help, i don't want labels under every candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]need a little help, the code below works fine but it looks so dirty because it puts labels under each candle, is there a way to prevent this.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='4EMA', shorttitle='4EMA', overlay=true)
show = input.bool(true, title="Cash Control Strateji", group='Stratejiler')
Length1 = input.int(8, minval=1)
Length2 = input.int(13, minval=1)
Length3 = input.int(21, minval=1)
Length4 = input.int(55, minval=1)

xPrice = close

xEMA1 = ta.ema(xPrice, Length1)
xEMA2 = ta.ema(xPrice, Length2)
xEMA3 = ta.ema(xPrice, Length3)
xEMA4 = ta.ema(xPrice, Length4)

plot(xEMA1, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='4EMA 8')
plot(xEMA2, color=color.new(color.green, 0), title='4EMA 13')
plot(xEMA3, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), title='4EMA 21')
plot(xEMA4, color=color.new(color.red, 0), title='4EMA 55')

a = ta.ema(close, Length1)
b = ta.ema(close, Length2)
c = ta.ema(close, Length3)
d = ta.ema(close, Length4)

condition = (a>b) and (b>c) and (c>d)

plotshape(show ? condition : na,title='Heikinashi Strateji', text='Ha.Al.', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Comment: When do you want to have them?

Answer (score 0):

if you want them just on the first occurrence you can do this:

```
plotshape(show ? condition and not condition[1] : na,title='Heikinashi Strateji', text='Ha.Al.', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: No, I want to create a buy signal when all three conditions are fulfilled and sell at the first failure of these three conditions.

Comment: What I posted gives a buy signal at the first occurrence.... Flip it around for a sell ie. not condition and condition[1]